# How can I fix this jqueryui function

Tags: jquery

```
$(function){
    $('.box').draggable ();
    $('#box1').draggable ({scroll: true}); 
    $('#box2').draggable ({axis: x});
    $('#box3').draggable ({axis:y});
});
```

Jslint Error:

> '$' was used before it was define
>          Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.)

Comment: you can start from here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: where and how you include jquery with external CDN or inside you bundle? add some code please